# PHP upload to a imgur Album does not work?

Tags: php, api, imgur

im trying to upload to my imgur Account's album, however, the upload works, but it looks like its gonna uploaded as anonym/public?

here's my code:

```
<?php

$client_id = "465xxx8c44294";
$image = file_get_contents("../images/d4487317c3xxx93210b293c2e.jpg");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => base64_encode($image)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => base64_encode($image), 'album' => 'nqxxxGE'));

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$reply = json_decode($reply);
printf('<img height="180" src="%s" >', $reply->data->link);
```

any advice?

Comment: I want to have this picture placed in my AlbumID "nqxxxGE" on my Imgur account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add image to album, according [doc](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139), you need to pass album `id`. Make sure you've generated token that has access to secret albums.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486480/how-do-you-get-access-token-and-refresh-token-from-imgur) you can find some tips about tokens.

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    array(
        'image' => base64_encode($image), 
        'album' => '5' // 5 - your album id
    ) 
);
```

You can check you albums id using [this](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#c13fe966-0f8f-425d-9247-298e302e1bc0) api.

### To refresh token:

If a user has authorized their account but you no longer have a valid `access_token` for them, then a new one can be generated by using the `refresh_token`.

To obtain a new access token, your application performs a `POST` to `https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token`. The request must include the following parameters to use a refresh token:

`refresh_token`: The refresh token returned from the authorization code exchange

`client_id`:    The client_id obtained during application registration

`client_secret`:    The client secret obtained during application registration.

`grant_type`:   As defined in the OAuth2 specification, this field must contain a value of: `refresh_token`.

As long as the user has not revoked the access granted to your application, the response includes a new access token. A response from such a request is shown below:

```
{
    "access_token":"5c3118ebb73fbb275945ab340be60b610a3216d6",
    "refresh_token":"d36b474c95bb9ee54b992c7c34fffc2cc343d0a7",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "account_username":"saponifi3d"
}
```

Add the refresh part at the start of your script. Something like:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'refresh_token' => $refreshToken, // Your refresh_token
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret, //Your client_secret
    'grant_type' =>  'refresh_token'
]);

//Keep in mind that refreshToken and clientSecret are obtained during registration.

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$reply = json_decode($reply);
$accessToken = $reply->access_token;
```

Comment: yeah, i did that, but its just not adding it. is that the public ID? or i do not have any clue how to get the "ID" of the album o_O

Comment: @Thomas should be public. Check using api in the updated answer :)

Comment: Okay, so i can't upload to hidden albums?

Comment: @Thomas I am not sure, just try to get all your album ids. I provided you the [link](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#c13fe966-0f8f-425d-9247-298e302e1bc0) howto do this. I think, there are also hidden albums, so should be possible to use it by id.

Comment: @Thomas check your cliend id has not expired, for me it works fine using secret albums.

Comment: lol, it was because i just created a "public" token, which had no access to my album.
Now, i have a access_token. but that expires after 28 days :/

Comment: @Thomas you can [refresh](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#3f80c836-8f49-4fb1-95a7-a4b058265d72) it :)

Comment: Yeah saw that! But i need to manually do it every 28 days? :(

Comment: @Thomas I've edited my answer to provide you some usefull link about tokens. If you pass `refresh_token`  you can generate a new `access_token`. Just add this into your script as a first steps.

Comment: Thanks man!

Could you provide me the code with the refresh_token part? Im unable to add in to my script

Comment: @Thomas updated. Please, read the docs for more info, you have all the needed links :)

Comment: you are my champ!

Comment: @Thomas you are welcome. Accept an answer if it helped, so that others can also use this solution.

Comment: Im still trying to figure it out, for now im not able to include it :D (its not working for now) hehe